# How to pass ref from parent element to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I am facing a problem which causes a lot of headaches and I just can't solve it.
I have a component which is used through the whole application (about 100 times in total) and the main goal of it to render some list based on children *(children is a function which returns the child component)* and payload *(payload is an array of objects, which holds information about future children)*.

```
<GenericList
    children={this.renderElement}
    payload={this.state.treeData}
    // other props...
/>
```

Here is the `renderElement`

```
renderElement = (role) => {
        return (
            <BaseListItem>
                <div className="fb jCenter">
                    <Text
                        title={role.Name}
                    >
                        {role.Name}
                    </Text>
                </div>
            </BaseListItem>
        );
    };
```

`renderElement` can both return RFC or RCC.
Inside `GenericList` I should somehow manage it to pass `ref` to RFC or RCC.
The Part of code, which implements that logic is this

```
cloneChildrenElement({ payload, children, selected, payloadSortBy }) {
    if (payload && payload.length) {
        const { selectBy, scrollToIndex, idToScrollIndex } = this.props;
        const data = sortPayload(payload, payloadSortBy);

        return data.map((item, index) => {
            return cloneElement(children(item), {
                item,
                isActive,
                key: index,
                onDoubleClick: this.handleDblClick,
                ref: (node) => {
                    console.log(node, 'node');
                    if (Number.isInteger(scrollToIndex) || isActive) {
                        this.genericContentSelected = node;
                    }
                },
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have also tried to implement ref forwarding, but in that case, I should manually do it for all components that use that logic.
I want to know whether it's possible to achieve this by only making changes inside `GenericList` component.